# How is the multi-class support vector machine classifier implemented?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, machine-learning

I am using support vector machine (SVM) method with [`Classify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) to do multi-class.

Can anyone tell me the reference (paper) used by Wolfram *Mathematica* to develop the SVM method for the multi-class version?

---

We can get the version of multi-class method of SVM using Classfier Information

```
 ClassifierInformation[classifierSVM]

 Association[
"Method" -> "Support vector machine", "Number of classes" -> 8, 
 "Number of features" -> 640, "Number of training examples" -> 1600, 
 "Number of extracted features" -> 340, 
 "Kernel type" -> "Radial basis function", 
 "Soft margin parameter" -> 1, 
 "Multiclass method" -> "One-versus-one"].
```

I this case, the Multiclass method is "one vs one"

Comment: Does *Mathematica* ever disclose the details of the implementations? I don't thinks that information is available other than what can be guessed from `Method` names, as in *"RandomForest, classify using Breiman-Cutler ensembles of decision trees"*

Comment: @rhermans, I don't know.

Comment: You might want to write to Wolfram Research and ask them. I can recall someone here on mathematica.SE recommending this and saying that they (Wolfram) were very forthcoming with their sources/papers.