# Classification problem using SVM methods

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, machine-precision, machine-learning

I am running SVM on mathematica and I a used this code with classes:

```
class1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 640}];

class2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 640}];

trainset = Association[{"class1" -> class1, "class2" -> class2}]

c = Classify[trainset, Method -> {All -> {"SupportVectorMachine",     "KernelType" -> "RadialBasisFunction","MulticlassMethod" -> "OneVersusOne"}}]
```

[image]

1)Here What is the **the number of extracted features?**
2) Normally, by default the "SoftMarginParameter"=1.

When I add the "SoftMarginParameter", I get an error:

```
 c = Classify[trainset, Method -> {All -> {"SupportVectorMachine",     "KernelType" -> "RadialBasisFunction","MulticlassMethod" -> "OneVersusOne","SoftMarginParameter"->.2}}]
```

**Part::pkspec1: The expression MachineLearning`PackageScope`MaxLoc[Null] cannot be used as a part specification. >>
Set::shape: Lists {MachineLearning`SupportVectorMachine`PackagePrivate`logbestGamma$803479,MachineLearning`SupportVectorMachine`PackagePrivate`logbestCost$803479} and Log[Null[[MachineLearning`PackageScope`MaxLoc[Null]]]]/Log[2] are not the same shape. >>
Part::pkspec1: The expression MachineLearning`PackageScope`MaxLoc[Null] cannot be used as a part specification. >>
Set::shape: Lists {MachineLearning`SupportVectorMachine`PackagePrivate`logbestGamma$803479,MachineLearning`SupportVectorMachine`PackagePrivate`logbestCost$803479} and Log[Null[[MachineLearning`PackageScope`MaxLoc[Null]]]]/Log[2] are not the same shape. >>**

Comment: Have you tried rescaling them, like multiply them by $10^4$?

Comment: @rcollyer, I discover the problem, I think it is not depend on data! I edited my question with an example

Comment: It seems setting `"GammaScalingParameter"`, too, avoids the issue. I used `1/(340 Sqrt[2])` which is what `ClassifierInformation[c, "Options"]` told me.

Comment: @rcollyer, I have already tried that. But, how can we calculate it, and another problem is ClassifierInformation[c] does not return the same thing each time, you can check http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104417/how-is-the-multi-class-support-vector-machine-classifier-implemented?noredirect=1#comment283471_104417 : I have run the same code  some days before and it did not get the same thing

Comment: @rcollyer, I find that it is not well documented. No information about parameter and options!?

Comment: As to your previous question, we're using [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). As to the changing parameter, the default depends on the data set, itself. So, if the data set changes, it changes. I do not know how it is calculated, though.

Comment: @rcollyer, Thanks